# How to map chloropleth of average income (python/ geopandas)

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I want to preface this by saying I'm a total beginner with coding!

I have a geojson file that has a shape/ coordinates and can be mapped with geopandas. I was able to easily map a cloropleth of population density using code i found elsewhere and wrote myself from what i read on the geopandas website, but it got way trickier when I was asked to map income data. essentially i have this huge dataframe organized like this:

| census tract | less than 10,000 | 10-20,000 (and so on) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tract1 | 3 | 5 |
| tract2 | 6 | 7 |

I made the data up of course, but that's the gist. The columns are income ranges, and the rows are census tracts in los angeles county.

I want to map a cloropleth where each of the income ranges (less than 10,000, 10-20,000, and so on) are categories that are each colored differently, but I don't know how to plot that information without having a column for average income in that tract, which i can't even get because the data was given in ranges (10-20,000, 20-30,000, etc)

Is there a way to do this?

I already went through and designated a color for each one as such:
color_dict = 'less than 10,000': 'lightcoral'

The closest I've gotten was with this code:

```
%matplotlib inline
ax = latin_hispanic_income.plot(column='total', scheme='QUANTILES', k=16, \
             cmap='plasma', legend=True,
             legend_kwds={'loc': 'center left', 'bbox_to_anchor':(1,0.5)})
ax.set_ylim(33.7, 34)
ax.set_xlim(-118.5, -118)
ax.set_title('Average income by census tract in LA county', fontdict= 
            {'fontsize':10})
```

Which spat out this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxTsu.png)

It's pretty close to what I want, with 16 different quantiles in the legend (there are 16 total income ranges in the data), but the actual map hasn't plotted by income, it's plotted by the 'total' column, ie the column with the total number of people. So it's essentially just a map of population density.

Comment: You can only assign one color per shape, so how do you want to plot the number of people in each category for many categories?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Essentially what I thought I could do was figure out the average income range for each tract and then assign that income range a color. So essentially the number of people becomes insignificant and I only plot area by average income. Since posting this I was able to add in another column to my data frame that has the average income range for each tract, but I still can't map anything using that column since it's a range (< 10,000, 10-20,000 etc etc) and therefore not an integer. If you have any other ideas about how to plot this info definitely feel free to let me know too

Comment: However you’re creating that range - I’d turn it into a number and plot that

Comment: This looks relevant: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1269

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Oh thanks for the link! That's super helpful for my current categorical plot. Unfortunately, per your previous comment, I'm not creating the ranges, the data comes like that (under 10,000-20,000, it lists 4 people, within the next it lists 6 people, etc) b/c that's how the questions on the census are formatted. It doesn't show how much each person who filled it out makes, just the range. I doubt I'm the first person to want to map income though so I'm thinking there must be data somewhere out there where it gives averages, so I'll look for that as well!

Comment: no I'm just saying you could assign that range a numerical value just for the purposes of determining the color. Saying that "<10,000" is blue isn't all that different from "<10,000" --> 5000.0 --> blue. this doesn't seem different to me from assigning colors manually based on the categories